# how to get the earliest date Excel support programmatically

Tags: c#, excel, date, limit

Excel AddIn, C#, UDF, 
MyUDF calls a web service to retrieve certain date. Sometimes the date returned is not in range of Jan-1-1900 to Dec-31-9999 (Excel Date Range). E.g. in one case returned date is Jan-2-0002 (valid in C# but not valid in Excel), then Excel crashes.  I do not hard code "Jan-1-1900", so wonder if there is a way that I can get it programmatically. thanks

Comment: Honestly, I would hard code it or put the date range in a config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside Excel, convert the date corresponding to `1` into a string that you can parse:

```
=TEXT(1,"dd-mm-yyyy")
```

which should give you 01-01-1900 or 02-01-1904 depending on the [date system](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180162/en-us) chosen (hat tip to barrowc!). Note how the date systems don't only differ by four years but also by the fact that in one case the value 1 corresponds to January 1st (in 1900) and in the other it is 0 which corresponds to January 1st (in 1904). For a given Workbook, the [Workbook.Date1904 Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193264.aspx) can tell you which date system is being used.

Comment: +1 just watch out for the `Workbook.Date1904` property being set though - this will cause the dates to start at 1904/01/02 rather than 1900/01/01 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193264.aspx

Comment: Thanks @barrowc - I added some information about that. I guess I had too much confidence in "things will never change" once again...